# Convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a(n) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n})^{n^{2}}}{n \cdot e^n}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How may I prove that the following summation converges or diverges?

I tried to prove that $a(n)$ doesn't go to zero (which proves that the summation diverges) but finding the limit was too hard.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a(n) =$$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n})^{n^{2}}}{n \cdot e^n}$$

**Edit I proved that it's smaller than: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n^2}}{(n \cdot e^n)}$$ if I could prove that the latter converges then I solved it**

Comment: Have you tried expanding the parentheses and considering this as the sum of two series?

Comment: @OsamaGhani I can't expand them since it's to the power on n

Comment: Do you "want" to use $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le e$$?

Comment: The comparison doesn't help, since $2^{n^2}/e^n=(2^n/e)^n$, and $2^n/e\gt2$ if $n\ge3$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy . It is not. See my A.

Comment: My edit was for minor typos.

Comment: $a(n)$ does go to $0$. For all $n$ we have $\ln a(n)\le$ $ n^2 \ln (1+1/n)-\ln n-n<$ $n^2(1/n)-\ln n-n= $ $=\ln(1/n).$

Answer (score 2):

When $n$ is even we have $$\ln a(n)=n^2\ln(1+1/n)-\ln n-n=$$ $$=n^2(1/n-1/2n^2+1/3n^3-...)-\ln n-n>$$ $$>n^2(1/n-1/2n^2)-\ln n-n=-1/2-\ln n.$$ So $a(n)>1/n\sqrt e$ when $n$ is even.

Every $a(n)$ is positive so $$\sum_na(n)\ge \sum_{n \;\text {even}}a(n)\ge$$ $$\ge\sum_{n \;\text {even}}1/n\sqrt e=\infty.$$